# Fetch values from excel to python

Tags: python, pandas, openpyxl

I want to fetch value from excel per minute, as the value keeps on updating per second.

```
from openpyxl import workbook

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('C:\Zerodha\Pi\LinkExcel\Default MW.xlsx')
ws = wb.active
cell_range = ws['B2']
a3 = ws.cell(row=2, column=2)
```

Tried the code, it extracts value but the one before the workbook was last saved.

Comment: Your question isn't clear.

Comment: I will elaborate. I am working on stock market data, It changes every second. I want to copy only one relevant cell every minute. When I run the above it works well once but as the value updates it doesn't get updated in python, even after running the code again.

Answer (score 0):

Re-written answer:

Um so, I think you do not understand how saving and loading data works. The reason why you need to save the workbook before you access it from python is because if you do not save it, the values are not actually updated in the file. They only update in the file if you save the workbook, and your code reads from the data in the .xlsx file itself, and as I said, it only updates when you save the excel document. There is no other way to do this with excel other than saving it after a value is changed.

Comment: This works if I save the file and again run the code. Then only the value gets updated.
If I change value and run the code without saving it gives me old values.

Comment: @Puneet Tewani I changed my answer. You have to save the workbook to access the values